# Get value from EditText on enter

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide, onkeypress

I've a little problem with my `keypressfcn`. If the user types something into the edittextbox I would like to start a function from another m-file if they pressed enter.

Actually it looks like this:

```
% --- Executes on key press with focus on ET_variabelpos_9 and none of its controls.
function ET_variabelpos_9_KeyPressFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to ET_variabelpos_9 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  structure with the following fields (see UICONTROL)
%   Key: name of the key that was pressed, in lower case
%   Character: character interpretation of the key(s) that was pressed
%   Modifier: name(s) of the modifier key(s) (i.e., control, shift) pressed
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

%Modifier um zu überprüfen, ob die Pfeiltastengedrückt wurden
val=double(get(gcf,'CurrentCharacter'))

%28 => leftArrow
%29 => rightArrow
%30 => upArrow
%31 => downArrow


if val == 30
    sw1 = get(handles.ET_variabelpos_9,'String')
    %Relative Position anfahren (Hoch)
    gotorelativ_up_function(sw1,0,8);

elseif val == 31
    sw1 = get(handles.ET_variabelpos_9,'String')
    %Relative Position anfahren (Hoch)
    gotorelativ_down_function(sw1,0,8);
end
```

I read the value from the EditText and transfer it to the function `gotorelativ_down_function` or `gotorelativ_up_function`.

It works fine, the only problem is, that the user needs to press enter twice to get the current value of the edittext.

Answer (score 0):

I´ve solved it. I use the wrong function. The code should use in the callbackfunction of the Edit Text.